# What is the difference between using "any" type in functions and using function overloading in typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

Because if we use `any` datatype we require the usage of `typeof` and then differentiate the logic based on the type.

So what is the need of having another concept of function overloading in typescript?

Comment: If you'll perceive the public methods of your type as an API to the world (as they are), you'll realize that relying on a function overloading is much more expressive and declarative (being able to explicitly declare the types you're expecting as a valid argument). Using `any` with `typeof` does not provide any of those benefits, aside from its imperative approach.

Comment: could you give some code examples?